# iphone app with ability to upload images to a calendar

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.5

Hi i have been approached to create an app which allows users to upload images either daily or weekly etc. with a description and title and add these images to a calendar. The images could then be viewed in sequence or via the calendar.

I am quite new to app development and so far have only done basic apps. 
How difficult is it to create an app of this scale? 
Can anyone recommend any tutorials that might help?
Also what kind of time frame would i be looking at?

any feedback would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Can Calendar event attach images? I doubt.

Comment: yea good point not too sure about that... thats why im asking

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **You Can't** . iOS Calendar events cannot attach images. You have to write your calendar apps.